# How can I concatenate a Series onto a DataFrame with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a `DataFrame`:

```
students = pd.DataFrame([
    ['Alex'],
    ['Lauren'],
])
```

How can I concatenate a `Series` and create a new `DataFrame`? For example, I'd like:

```
>>> marks = pd.Series([.8, .75])
>>> students.concat(marks).values
[['Alex', .8],
 ['Lauren', .75]]
```

I know that I could use:

```
students['marks'] = marks
```

But that would mutate `students`.

I've tried:

```
 >>> pd.concat([students, marks])
 …
 AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute '_data'
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can convert to DataFrame and concatenate afterwards:

```
>>> pd.concat([students, pd.DataFrame(marks)], axis=1)
        0     0
0    Alex  0.80
1  Lauren  0.75
```

Comment: This was simple but I suspected it for that same reason. Trust your intuition!

Answer (score 1):

To retain your original dataframe, you could first copy the dataframe, and then add the column:

```
students2 = students.copy(deep=True)
students2['marks'] = marks
```

Comment: Ya, there are a couple ways I could do it through explicitly copying the DataFrame… but I'd like to do it in one expression, so I can pass the result along to something else.

Comment: In that case, couldn't you just define your own function which does the above and returns the new dataframe?

Comment: I could! But this seems like it should be a fairly standard usecase, and I'd like to find out the "normal" way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would normally do

`students["marks"] = marks`

But `pd.concat` works as well.

Comment: This will overwrite rows if multiple "marks" rows exist.